# How to cache Iframes and prevent unmount when react router switches?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've 4 routes, 3 of them have external embeds. Each time route changes they get unmounted and have to refetched when you get back to their particular route.

I want to be able to do two things:

1. If user navigates to another page do not unmount the Iframe component, or alternative that gets the same results.
2. Once the current route has loaded start rendering other pages (fetching iframes) in background.

Comment: Not sure if there's a better approach but I had this problem before and I ended up hiding the iframes instead of removing them from the DOM

Comment: how did you render it where the componenet needed to be? suppose i hide them and render everything outside of switch/router then how did you use them?

Comment: You can try one thing, render the component outside the router and memoize it and then pass the memoized form to the router.

Comment: kind of leaning into this React.memo direction.. lets see

Comment: I have the same situation here can you explain how? @KartikMalik